# Finding the set of points with maximum distance from a given point (where all points are probability vectors)

Tags: probability, geometry

Consider the set of points $S = \{(x, y, z) \;|\; x,\, y,\, z \in [0, 1], \,x + y + z = 1\}$. Given a  point $p$ in $S$, how would one go about finding the set of points in $S$ having maximum Euclidean distance from $p\,$?

I worked out the two-dimensional version (take the reflection of $p$ about the perpendicular bisector of the line $y = 1-x$), but find myself unable to generalize it... I am actually interested in the 12-dimensional case.

Comment: The furthest point will be one or more of $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ so check each one (or just find which is the maximum of $x,y,z$)

Comment: Do you know about differential calculus and its application to the study of the extrema of functions?

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ you describe is an equilateral triangle. So you're asking about which point in that triangle is farthest away from a given point in that triangle. It has to be one or more of the corners. At any point other than a corner, there has to be one direction where you can still get farther away from $p$.

Which means your 2d analogon is incorrect as well: the point furthest from a given point on that segment would be one or both of its endpoints, not the reflection in the perpendicular bisector. Or perhaps the other way round: if what you need is correctly described by this reflection, then it's not the set of points at maximal distance.